# Can I add hover on whole svg not only on path

Tags: html, css, svg

```css
svg :hover{
    fill: #fff;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

When I add hover on svg this effect only works when I hover path of that svg. Thus can be problem when I have some svg with path on borders and empty space in middle. Can I somehow add this effect when I hover that empty space.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
svg:hover path {
  fill: #ffff;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<svg width="22" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path
                  d="M20.925 3.641H3.863L3.61.816A.896.896 0 0 0 2.717 0H.897a.896.896 0 1 0 0 1.792h1l1.031 11.483c.073.828.52 1.726 1.291 2.336C2.83 17.385 4.099 20 6.359 20c1.875 0 3.197-1.87 2.554-3.642h4.905c-.642 1.77.677 3.642 2.555 3.642a2.72 2.72 0 0 0 2.717-2.717 2.72 2.72 0 0 0-2.717-2.717H6.365c-.681 0-1.274-.41-1.53-1.009l14.321-.842a.896.896 0 0 0 .817-.677l1.821-7.283a.897.897 0 0 0-.87-1.114ZM6.358 18.208a.926.926 0 0 1 0-1.85.926.926 0 0 1 0 1.85Zm10.015 0a.926.926 0 0 1 0-1.85.926.926 0 0 1 0 1.85Zm2.021-7.243-13.8.81-.57-6.341h15.753l-1.383 5.53Z"
                  fill="#69707D"
                  fill-rule="nonzero"
                />
              </svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with your selector. The space in `svg :hover` means that the rule only gets executed when you hover over any descendant element of the svg. Instead, change it to `svg:hover path` which will work when hovering over any part of the svg, but only apply to the path.

```css
svg:hover path{
    fill: #ffff;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<svg width="22" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
              d="M20.925 3.641H3.863L3.61.816A.896.896 0 0 0 2.717 0H.897a.896.896 0 1 0 0 1.792h1l1.031 11.483c.073.828.52 1.726 1.291 2.336C2.83 17.385 4.099 20 6.359 20c1.875 0 3.197-1.87 2.554-3.642h4.905c-.642 1.77.677 3.642 2.555 3.642a2.72 2.72 0 0 0 2.717-2.717 2.72 2.72 0 0 0-2.717-2.717H6.365c-.681 0-1.274-.41-1.53-1.009l14.321-.842a.896.896 0 0 0 .817-.677l1.821-7.283a.897.897 0 0 0-.87-1.114ZM6.358 18.208a.926.926 0 0 1 0-1.85.926.926 0 0 1 0 1.85Zm10.015 0a.926.926 0 0 1 0-1.85.926.926 0 0 1 0 1.85Zm2.021-7.243-13.8.81-.57-6.341h15.753l-1.383 5.53Z"
              fill="#69707D"
              fill-rule="nonzero"
            />
          </svg>
```

Comment: you was faster than me

Comment: @Eymen Yep. Plus I explained the issue and didn't just dump code

Comment: hahaha, it is fantastic